# Space in stringified HTML causes invalid expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am testing this on jQuery 1.9.1.

I have a pretty standard plugin with an element in the `options` object like:

```
        wrapper: '\
            <div class="modal_wrapper">\
                <div class="modal_outer">\
                <div class="modal_inner">&nbsp;</div>\
                </div>\
            </div>',
```

Where the spaces are tabs. When using it with jquery `$(options.wrapper)` it breaks with:

```
uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <div class="modal_wrapper">                  <div class="modal_outer">                   <div class="modal_inner">&nbsp;</div>                   </div>              </div>
```

However I test this with jQuery 1.8.3 and it works.

Has there been some kind of change? Anyone else getting this problem? I have Google searched but it appears this is one of those things that is not so easy to Google search.

I get it in both Firefox (latest) and Chrome (latest).

Comment: fiddle plsssssssssssssss

Comment: And between double quotes ?

Comment: It seems Sizzel's bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [a bug](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/1264) that was closed two months ago, which is after jQuery 1.9.1 was released.

Update to 1.10.2 and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

**jQuery 1.9.1**

```
var options = {
     wrapper: '\
            <div class="modal_wrapper">\
                <div class="modal_outer">\
                <div class="modal_inner">&nbsp;</div>\
                </div>\
            </div>'
}

var html = $.parseHTML(options.wrapper);


console.log($(html));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/steo/8bTbd/

as of **jQuery > 1.9.1** it seems to work without `$.parseHTML`